# QPaint onto QGLFramebufferObject texture?

Tags: qt, opengl, textures, vbo

I am trying to learn how to use QPainter with a QGLFramebufferObject.  When I try to display the texture in a QGLWidget, it is not visible.  (complete code below)

The end goal is to use QPainter to draw text onto textures and then alpha blend the texture overtop of the 2D line geometry.

texture.pro

```
QT += core gui widgets opengl

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES = main.cpp
HEADERS = main.h
```

main.h

```
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QGLFunctions>

class glview : public QGLWidget, protected QGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit glview(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~glview();
    QSize sizeHint() const;

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();

private:
    quint32 vbo_id[2], texture_id;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QPainter>
#include "main.h"

struct vrtx {
    GLint   x;
    GLint   y;
    GLubyte r;
    GLubyte g;
    GLubyte b;
}__attribute__((packed)) line_geo[] = {
//   x, y,   r, g, b
    {1, 1, 255, 0, 0},
    {1, 2, 0, 255, 0},
    {1, 2, 0, 255, 0},
    {2, 2, 255, 0, 0},
    {2, 2, 255, 0, 0},
    {2, 1, 0, 255, 0},
    {2, 1, 0, 255, 0},
    {1, 1, 255, 0, 0},
};

struct txtr_vrtx {
    GLint   x;
    GLint   y;
    GLint   tx;
    GLint   ty;
}__attribute__((packed)) txtr_geo[] = {
//   x, y, tx,ty
    {3, 1, 0, 0},
    {3, 2, 0, 1},
    {4, 2, 1, 1},
    {4, 1, 1, 0},
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    glview widget;
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}

glview::glview(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{

}

glview::~glview()
{

}

QSize glview::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(500, 300);
}

void glview::initializeGL()
{
    initializeGLFunctions();
    qglClearColor(Qt::white);

    glGenBuffers(2, vbo_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(line_geo), line_geo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(txtr_geo), txtr_geo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    QGLFramebufferObject fbo(100, 100, QGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil/*GL_TEXTURE_2D*/);
    fbo.bind();
    texture_id = fbo.texture();

    QPainter painter(&fbo);
    painter.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100, Qt::blue);
    painter.end();

    fbo.release();
}

void glview::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void glview::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 5, 0, 3, -1, 1);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[0]);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(struct vrtx), 0);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(struct vrtx), ((char*)NULL + 8));
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, sizeof(line_geo) / sizeof(struct vrtx));

    //glColor4ub(0, 0, 255, 255);
    //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[1]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(struct txtr_vrtx), 0);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(struct txtr_vrtx), ((char*)NULL + 8));
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: +1 for self-contained test case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QGLFramebufferObject instance is destroyed when leaving initializeGL(). This results in deleting the texture too. You need to keep the QGLFramebufferObject alive until the texture is no longer needed.

Comment: OK, I declared the QGLFramebufferObject in the class definition so it would persist after initializeGL().  I now get a black box.  I added a fbo->toImage() and then saved the image to a png file.  The png is blank.  There seems to be something wrong between the QPainter and the QGLFramebufferObject.

Comment: That's because you have a buffer bound. The GL paint engine does not use buffer objects so having something bound to the ARRAY_BUFFER binding point will lead to unexpected results. Do glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) before using QPainter to paint on the FBO.

Comment: Yep, glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) before the QPainter fixed it, Thanks.  In Qt 5.2, http://dangelog.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/using-fbos-instead-of-pbuffers-in-qt-5-2/ suggests QOpenGLFramebufferObject along with QOpenGLPaintDevice instead of QGLFramebufferObject.  Is this the better way to go?

Comment: Migrating to the newer, more modern QOpenGL classes is advisable in general, although you probably won't gain much with your existing code. QGLFramebufferObject and QOpenGLFramebufferObject are more or less the same, except that the QGL variant does not receive any development anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code.  Also with alpha bending.

main.h

```
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QGLFunctions>
#include <QGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QFont>

class glview : public QGLWidget, protected QGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit glview(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~glview();
    QSize sizeHint() const;

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();

private:
    QGLFramebufferObject *fbo;
    QFont font;
    quint32 vbo_id[2], texture_id;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include "main.h"

struct vrtx {
    GLint   x;
    GLint   y;
    GLubyte r;
    GLubyte g;
    GLubyte b;
}__attribute__((packed)) line_geo[] = {
//   x, y,   r, g, b
    {1, 1, 255, 0, 0},
    {1, 2, 0, 255, 0},
    {1, 2, 0, 255, 0},
    {2, 2, 255, 0, 0},
    {2, 2, 255, 0, 0},
    {2, 1, 0, 255, 0},
    {2, 1, 0, 255, 0},
    {1, 1, 255, 0, 0},
};

struct txtr_vrtx {
    GLint   x;
    GLint   y;
    GLint   tx;
    GLint   ty;
}__attribute__((packed)) txtr_geo[] = {
//   x, y, tx,ty
    {3, 1, 0, 0},
    {3, 2, 0, 1},
    {4, 2, 1, 1},
    {4, 1, 1, 0},
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    glview widget;
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}

glview::glview(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    font.setFamily("Helvetica");
}

glview::~glview()
{
    delete fbo;
}

QSize glview::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(500, 300);
}

void glview::initializeGL()
{
    initializeGLFunctions();
    qglClearColor(Qt::white);

    glGenBuffers(2, vbo_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(line_geo), line_geo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(txtr_geo), txtr_geo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);       // must unbind for QPainter

    fbo =  new QGLFramebufferObject(100, 100, GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    fbo->bind();
    texture_id = fbo->texture();

    QPainter painter(fbo);
    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
    font.setPointSize(20);
    painter.setFont(font);
    painter.drawText(0, 60, "FBO");
    painter.end();

    fbo->release();
}

void glview::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void glview::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 5, 0, 3, -1, 1);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[0]);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(struct vrtx), 0);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(struct vrtx), ((char*)NULL + 8));
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, sizeof(line_geo) / sizeof(struct vrtx));

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[1]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(struct txtr_vrtx), 0);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(struct txtr_vrtx), ((char*)NULL + 8));
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glFlush();
}
```